# How to quit from Git from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, github

I'm a beginner at Github and trying to add and delete the repository on my local computer.
But I tried to quit from GitHub(master), but every time I started the Ubuntu, it started with GitHub(master) as a default, how can I change the ubuntu to be started as $ as before?

Thankyou in advance for your reply!

[image: some text here]

Comment: I'm most curios how do you *enter Github* on your machine?

Comment: check if you have `.git` folder in you home directory where terminal starts

Answer (score 0):

This is the prompt of your shell which has been configured to look for if you are currently placed inside a directory "inside" a git repository checkout.

If yes, it prints relevant information to the current state of the git repository checkout, which is very useful when using git at the command line.

You most likely by accident have created a `.git` folder in your home directory.  If it is an error then just remove it, and your prompt should return to what you have seen before.